# Issue in using TRY_PARSE in CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tryparse

I need to validate the dates with different formats like 
`Thursday March 15, 2018, 05-21-1995, 04.03.1934` and I may get Invalid Dates like `N/A, #### etc.,`. I am using the Following Query to validate the date in Stored procedure, here I insert the date into the date column and set Error Flag If there is an Invalid date.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(date_column,date_error) 
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US') is NULL THEN date_column
            ELSE TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US')
            END as date_column,
        CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US') is NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END as date_error
        FROM @temp_table;
```

I'm getting the Error as `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` for date value `####`.

Comment: What do you want the `case` expression to return?  One branch is a string and the other a date/time.  SQL Server decides that you want the date/time and you get a conversion error.

Comment: If it is an valid date I want to format the date and Insert into table, In case of invalid date I want to insert as it is and set the error flag.

Comment: what's your `table_name` DDL then? is `date_column` a string?

Comment: This implies you want to store your `datetime` as a `varchar`... This a bad idea (for so many reasons).

Comment: Yes. I am using varchar for date_column because I need to store invalid dates also like `N/A, ###`.

Comment: @Mdumanoj why cant you use NULL for invalid dates?

Comment: I need to show Invalid dates to the user for correction. So that I can't make that field NULL.

Comment: To expand on @GordonLinoff's comment : A `CASE` statement can't return different data-types for different rows, and your target table can't store different data-types in different rows.  This implies to me that you may need a new table structure; `INSERT INTO table_name (date_value, original_string_value) SELECT TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US'), date_column FROM @temp_table`.  This will give the original string for every row, the datetime value if the conversion succeeds or a NULL if the conversion fails.  But trying to store both strings and datetimes in one column is an error

Comment: Then have 2 fields. One which is a `date` or `datetime` column, and then another for the bad data. Then, once it's all fixed, get rid of the bad data column. Storing your dates as a `varchar` just means people can keep entering crap data... It won't solve the problem long term.

Comment: # character is used in creating temp tables. I think you may need to convert/cast to varchar first then use the try_parse. Also the above mentioned comments are gold. EG: try_parse(cast(date_column as varchar(100) ) AS datetime USING 'en-US')

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put two different types in one column

This may work for you

```
declare @T table (pk int identity primary key, varDt varchar(100));
insert into @T (varDt) values ('Thursday March 15, 2018'), ('05-21-1995'), ('N/A'), ('####'), ('easter'), ('');
declare @Tf table (pk int primary key, varDt varchar(100), needFix bit, dt datetime);
insert into @Tf
select t.pk, t.varDt 
     , case when TRY_PARSE(t.varDt AS datetime USING 'en-US') is null then 1 else 0 end as needFix
     , TRY_PARSE(t.varDt AS datetime USING 'en-US') as dt     
from @T t;
select * 
from @Tf tf 
order by needFix desc, pk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. As @gordon-linoff said we can't have two different datatypes in CASE WHEN Statement. So, I CAST the else statement to varchar.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(date_column,date_error) 
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US') is NULL THEN date_column
        ELSE CAST(TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US') AS varchar(max))
        END as date_column,
    CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(date_column AS datetime USING 'en-US') is NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as date_error
    FROM @temp_table;
```